# Set Panopto's speed manually

Tags: javascript, html, video, console

I am trying to use Panopto for my online lessons. I am trying to modify its code in the console in developer's instruments in order to be able to accelerate/decelerate the videos as I need.

For example, it lets you choose between 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75 and 2x. But I need something less rigid: I need to set that value to a different value (for example to 1.15x). Do you have any suggestions of how I can modify its source code or of what I could wirte in the console in order to do it?

I tried to search for the code lines where the speed is set. I only found this line, which is the HTML part:

```
<div id="playSpeedMultiplier">1x</div>
```

By just changing `playSpeedMultiplier` and setting to 5x (for a try using `playSpeedMultiplier=5;`), nothing happens.

How can I manage it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution:

1. Go in the Browser console
2. Type `document.querySelector("video").playbackRate = 5;` and press Enter